1tb disk error ubuntu
I'm new to ubuntu and i've just download it. When i try to to open my 1tb disk error appears:

What to do?

Show the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 please. Put it into your question as an edit

Your disk appears to be in the Microsoft file system, please repair it with the Microsoft file system application.

Often fast startup has set hibernation flag or bitlocker is on. Check Windows settings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation NTFS driver will not open hibernated NTFS to prevent loss of data when hibernation is restored by Windows. You may be able to manually mount read only.
